# Annoying refridgerator door

Tags: doors, kitchens, fridge

When I open my fridge to get stuff out (which take a short while because I need to snoop around), the door slowly goes back towards the closed state.

It never closes all the way and I've checked with the manufacturer - it's not a feature to conserve energy.

Imagine me, in the morning, buck naked, and just as I'm grabbing the ham from the back of the top shelf, the cold-cold door touches my shoulder or other parts. Not nice.

I'd like the door to stay at the angle I leave it or (if it's easier or quicker), to keep opening all the way until it hits the wall (which won't happen at a huge speed, precisely).

Since I'm not the superman, I can't tilt my building. What can be done about this annoyance?

Comment: Recommend wearing PJ's while grabbing ham from the back of the fridge in the morning...

Comment: I have the opposite problem.  Got a new fridge, the door likes to pop open and not stay closed and melt all of my food.

Comment: @endolith I suggest you apply the exact opposite of my solution. Lean the appliance backwards a bit by screwing the feet out of the fridge (if they're in front of it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the refrigerator, there *may* be a way to adjust the door directly.  If not, most models have height adjustable feet. Simply adjust the feet, so that the door stays in place or slowly opens.

How the adjustments are made, will be specific to the make and model. Check the manufacturer's documentation for your appliance, to determine how to make the adjustments on your unit.

Comment: +1 you likely need to slightly shorten the front foot under the hinge side.

Comment: Well, wouldn't you know! Behind the white board at the floor (which I've always though was an unremoveable part of the fridge), there's actually some legs that are, kind of, screwable. In fact, my fridge might be said to be standing on two large screws, instead of legs. No more chilly-butt syndrome in the morning. Thanks!